# How to output different commands in the same line?

Tags: macros, line-breaking

I'm trying to create a custom header command that outputs something like this:

> In MyCity, dd-mm-yyyy by Somebody with something

For that, I have custom commands to define each part

```
\newcommand{\myCity}[1]{\def\@myCity{#1}}
\newcommand{\myDate}[1]{\def\@myDate{#1}}
```

And yet another command to output it all

```
\newcommand{\makeThings}{

\ifdefined\@myCity

    \textbf{\@myCity}\textit{\@charDeathCity,\@charDeathDate})

\fi

\ifdefined\@myDate

    \textit{, \@myDate})

\fi

}
```

What I don't know, is how to have all the output from the \makeThings command in the same line. As it is, each if will be output in a different line. Can somebody, please, give me a help here?

Answer (score 2):

Blank lines are the same as `\par`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myCity}[1]{\def\@myCity{#1}}
\newcommand{\myDate}[1]{\def\@myDate{#1}}

\newcommand{\makeThings}{%
  \ifdefined\@myCity
    \textbf{\@myCity}\textit{\@charDeathCity,\@charDeathDate}) % space here
  \fi
  \ifdefined\@myDate
    \textit{, \@myDate})% no space here
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```